# Unix find which file contains binary snippet

Tags: unix

I was given binary file snippet and I need to find from 3 different files which file contains this binary snippet

Comment: So what is your question ? what do you want to achieve and what challenges are you facing ?

Comment: grep can also deal with binary data.

Comment: I have a file 'frag.txt' which contains some binary data, and you want to know which other files contain the same data.

Comment: files are /bin/bash , /bin/git-upload-pack